# Wordpress Contact Form 7: Can't see checkbox field

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, contact-form

I am working on [site](http://www.r90.ch/contact-form/) for a contact form.
As you can see on the right I need a checkbox. I've created it but I can't see the checkbox "field" to check. How can I solve it?

This is the code `[checkbox your-cb label_first "Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3"]`

Comment: Check your css and make sure you don't have a `-webkit-appearance:none;` on input fields.

Comment: Looks everything okay #forms input, 
#forms textarea,
#comment-form input, 
#comment-form textarea {
    border:1px solid #eeeeee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#7f7f7f;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:300;
    height:auto;
 width:100%;
    letter-spacing:0.5px;
    margin-bottom:18px;
    outline:none;
    padding:10px 15px 10px;   
 transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;